# Xamarin.Forms open browser appending javascript

Tags: jquery, xamarin, xamarin.forms, append

I am trying to implement a function in my project using Xamarin.Forms,
in which it requires to open browser to targeted URI and append the value in the **App's entry** to the broswer **website's input**

I am currently using Xamarin.Forms' [Device.OpenUri()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.openuri?view=xamarin-forms) method to open browser and i dont know if there is any way to append and execute a jquery script as we open the browser.

I imagine that it would be something like:

```
  Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://example.com")).AppendScript(<jquery script>);
```

maybe?

I have already search around for solutions but i only find the ones recommending "WebView" ways which not seem to suit my needs.

I appreciate all your help. Thank you!

Comment: If you just need to pass some values to the browser window can't you do it in the query string instead of passing JavaScript?

Comment: @Eifion Can you be a little bit more specific? By "query string" did you mean URI's parameters like "https://example.com?input_value=example" ? I dont know how we could interact with the web input's value via URI.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but this will only work if you're only trying to interact with a site that you've created. Having read your question again it looks like you're trying to  run JavaScript on other people's sites.